# Real world business is complex, did Corda support linear + ownable both state?

Tags: corda

Real world business is complex, Could I used both linearable + ownerable state implement complex business?

Answer (score 1):

You could in theory implement both interfaces in one state class. However, I'd argue that it doesn't make sense to do so:

- `OwnableState`s are designed to represent things like cash or oil, where it isn't the individual units owned that matters, but rather the total amount. For example, one might need $200 of cash, but they wouldn't need individual notes with specific serial numbers. This is why the node's vault has functionality to extract *X* amount of a given `OwnableState` subclass from the vault
- `LinearState`s are the opposite. They represent cases where one unit of a state isn't necessarily equivalent to another unit of the same state, even if they have the same parameters. For example, suppose property ownership is represented by `PropertyState`s. One property isn't equivalent to another, and you'd never request one hundred properties or $100,000 of property; the identities of the individual properties matter. Therefore a `PropertyState` would naturally be a `LinearState`